# Override a method from a base class that explicitly implements an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

[Edit]

Due to a little more complexity than was needed on the original post -- my apologies for that-- I'll try and simplify things a bit.

Originally, I had a base class that looked like this:

```
public class OurViewModel
{
  public bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState){...}
}
```

My class inherited and hid that method, using the new keyword:

```
public class MyViewModel : OurViewModel
{
  public new bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState) {...}
}
```

Meanwhile, the IValidatableObject interface has appeared:

```
public interface IValidatableObject
{
  IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
}
```

Now, OurViewModel has (sadly) also been changed.  It looks like this:

```
public class OurViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
  IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {..}
}
```

What I need to do now is again hide the Validate method in MyViewModel, but I can't figure out how do that with the current arrangement.  Is there a good way of going about this?

(FWIW, I agree that adding a new interface to a base class is not the optimal way to have done things, but it's what's happened here.)

---

[Original Post]

I'm having trouble overriding a method in one of my classes.  Someone changed the inheritance model of the base class from this:

```
public class OurViewModel : IntlViewModelBase<OurResources>
```

to this:

```
public class OurViewModel : IntlViewModelBase<OurResources>, IValidatableObject
```

IValidatableObject has a single method signature, `Validate()`:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
```

`OurViewModel` had a Validate method that looked like:

```
public bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
```

...and now is this after the change:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
```

My class, meanwhile, inherits from `OurViewModel`.  It used the `new` keyword to implement its own boolean version of Validate.

It seems I'm no longer able to hide the Validate method because my class does not implement IValidatableObject.  What's the proper way now for me to override that method?

Comment: It doesn't look like you were _ever_ able to override that method. It was not `virtual`.

Comment: I used the `new` keyword in my method to implment my own version of it-- perhaps I shouldn't have used the word 'override' in my description.  I don't appear to be able to use `new` this time around, so it sounds like I have to make the base method virtual?

Comment: @larryq So do you want to use the base class's implementation of `IValidatableObject`'s `Validate`, or do you want to use your own?  Also, do you have access to modify the base class at all?

Comment: `new` doesn't override - it _hides_ the base class method.

Comment: @Servy-- I do have access to the base class, and I want to use my own version of Validate.  
To answer your question below, I was using `new` in the original version of my class to hide the original base class version of Validate, but that no longer works with the explicit interface.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your immediate issue, but this sounds like a process problem to me. Class inheritance hierarchy changes should be proposed ahead of time and discussed amoungst the entire team before being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the point completely, but this compiles fine for me (used stub classes for `OurResources` and `IntlViewModelBase<T>`).

```
public class OurViewModel : IntlViewModelBase<OurResources>, IValidatableObject
{
    public bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : OurViewModel
{
    public new bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may not have been clear in my original post.  Sorry about that.  What's happened is the bool version of Validate is now gone, replaced by the IValidateableObject.Validate version of it.

Comment: @larryq Then you don't need `new` at all on the child object, as it's doesn't have any method to shadow.  You still haven't really described what you need to do, and what about that currently isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the new Validate method (IValidatableObject.Validate), you just need to add the virtual keyword.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
```

Comment: I'm told by the compiler that 'virtual' is not valid for explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Add virtual to the method in your base class, OurViewModel.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Does it need to be explicit? (e.g., can you declare the method in OurViewModel as this: "public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)")

Comment: @aprescott `virtual` makes no sense at all on an explicit interface implementation, which is why the compiler forbids it.  It cannot ever be shadowed or overridden, so the concept of `virtual` just doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've munged this question enough, and have decided to try again with a simpler version provided here-- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926964/overriding-hiding-an-explicity-implemented-interface-method)

Thanks to everyone who replied.  Could an admin close this thread or aim/link it toward the new question?  I'm not sure what the SO netiquette is on situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

Few things :

1.

> If for every method in your base class you want to have new
>   implementation in derived class then there is no point in deriving
>   from base. The main purpose of inheritance is code reuse. So you can simply remove the relationship from parent child.

2.

> Lets assume that in your base class there are some methods which are
>   actually inheriting. In that case I dont thing there should be a
>   problem with marking Base class's Interface member with Virtual
>   keyword and in derived class saying it as new.

--

> If you are asking about different way to implement this situation then
>   we need to know what's your aim. If the aim is to have derived member
>   to have new definition then better way would be Explicit
>   implementation of the interface in derived class.

Please mention the exact problem you are facing ? is it that you are not able to use new keyword or you are asking different ways to solve this situations.

Comment: The main "correct" usage of inheritance is substitutability.  For code reuse, encapsulation is generally better.

Comment: for me substitutability means  Lion should be able to be treated as Animal and we can pass around Animal object without worrying what actual type is inside...  Its TRUE that substitutability is important usage of Inheritance but then the name of the concept would have been substituion and not inheritance. Inheritance means Derived ones can use base members functionality ..ie. they inherit it.

Comment: Inheritance provides both code reuse and substitutability.  In situations where one *only* needs code reuse, encapsulation is generally better.  In cases where none of the things that are substitutable will need to reuse any implementation details, interfaces are often better than abstract classes.  My point is that if one wants to feed instances of one type to code that expects instances of another, that's a good sign that the former type should inherit from the latter *even if it replaces every single member*.

Comment: looks like its relative to every developer. For me code reuse is the main purpose of Inheritance and Substitutability is secondary(may be).  I seriously doubt if Encapsulation can acheive code reuse.