# Overriding / hiding an explicity implemented interface method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, explicit-implementation

I'm having trouble overriding a method that explicitly implements an interface.

I have two classes.  A base one called `OurViewModel`, and an inherited one called `MyViewModel`.  They share a method called `Validate`, and until recently I was able to hide the base version of the method, like so:

```
public class OurViewModel
{
  public bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState){ return true; }
}


public class MyViewModel : OurViewModel
{
  public new bool Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState) {return false;}
}
```

This all changed a couple of days ago.  A new interface has appeared on the scene--

```
public interface IValidatableObject
{
  IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
}
```

Subsequently, OurViewModel has also been changed.  I did not request this, but it happened and I have to live with it.  The class now looks like this:

```
public class OurViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
  IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {..}
}
```

I'm having difficult time figuring out how to override or hide this rewritten Validate method in MyViewModel.  If I try placing the `new` keyword the method signature (as I did originally) I get a compilation error.  I also can't declare the `Validate` method as virtual in OurViewModel, as it's explicitly implementing an interface.

What to do?  If I simply re-implement `Validate` in MyViewModel using the signature from IValidatableObject, will that hide the implementation in OurViewModel, or am I asking for trouble in some way because of inheritance rules?

Comment: again you made mistake in the question.. if the base member is not virtual you cant make it new in derived class.

Comment: @Dhananjay you are wrong...

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov  , so you meant if base member is non virtual you can still make it new ?

Comment: @Dhananjay definitely. Read [new Modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to implement this interface implicitly in the derived class as well.

```
public class MyViewModel : OurViewModel, IValidatableObject
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And then

```
OurViewModel v = new OurViewModel();
MyViewModel m = new MyViewModel();

IValidatableObject ivo = v;
ivo.Validate(null);

ivo = m;
ivo.Validate(null);
```

Besides if an interface is implemented explicitly, you can only access the implementation through a reference to the interface. Remember, if you try to do

```
OurViewModel v = new OurViewModel();
v.Validate(null);
```

It will call the original `Validate` method of the class, not the interface implementation. I think the old methods should be removed to avoid possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to implement IValidatableObject explicitly in Base class ?

> The solution would be - implement IValidatableObject implicitly  in
>   base class , mark it as virtual.

:-

> Then implement IValidatableObject in derived class , implicitely, and
>   mark it as virtual new. Dont forget to use interface name on derived
>   class definition.

This is little different approach as compated to answer by @Konstantin Vasilcov. 
Using this approach you can have more derived classes of MyViewModel who can override the behavior.